# Bootstrap results going awry in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, sass

I have an issue with a section of my site, but the issue only occurs in Chrome (haven't tried Firefox to be honest). In Safari, the "About" `div` (shown below) shows up just fine in the correct proportions, but in Chrome, the `p` element appears WAY too far down and most of it is over the left edge of the browser and unreadable, and the `#about_bg` section is way too far right and misbehaving as well. Any ideas?

The link is here: http://www.smoakvoiceover.com/#about

```
<!-- ABOUT -->
<div id="about" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="about_bg" class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
        <img id="question_glyph" class="center-block" src="img/question_glyph.png" alt="about" />
        <h3 id="question_glyph_alt" alt="about">ABOUT.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3 about_container">
        <p class="about_text">
          Outside of being "the voice," Bradley Smoak has had a variety of jobs throughout his career, most notably being an internationally acclaimed <a class="discreet" target="_blank" href="http://www.bradleysmoak.com">operatic soloist</a> featured at some of the top opera companies in the world.
          <br />
          <br />
          Other jobs have included bartender, boat renter, poker dealer, steakhouse cook, steakhouse waiter, steakhouse customer, website developer, illustrator, and computer game tester. From these incredibly diverse experiences, he brings a unique perspective to his voice acting and the ability to create a variety of specific, relatable characters that bring your copy to life.
          <br />
          <br />
          Originally from North Carolina, Bradley now makes his home in the wonderful Chicagoland area with his gorgeous wife and daughter, who put up with his "crazy voices" every day.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="about_arrow" class="text-center">
        <a href="#services"><span class="text-center glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the corresponding .scss code (compiled after through SASS):

```
#about {
  background: url('../img/about_bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin-bottom: -65px !important;
  z-index: 2 !important;
  position:relative;
  top:-57px !important;
}
#about_bg { 
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.825);
}
#question_glyph { 
  width: 50%;
  padding:220px 0px 270px 0px;
}
#question_glyph_alt { display: none; }
.about_container {
  margin: 250px auto;
  padding: 30px 35px;
  max-width:740px;
  text-align: left;
}
p.about_text { 
  color:#000 !important;
  font-size: 15px; 
}
#about_arrow > a {
  color: $white;
  width:40px;
  margin:0px auto;
  position:relative;
  bottom:100px;
  &:hover { color: $steel; }
}
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

Adding paddings and margins to the left and right sides of the Bootstrap columns will cause the columns to exceed the max width of the wrapper (if your columns are equal to 12) and the content will wrap.

Comment: Taken out all left/right padding and margins for the col-*-* `divs` and the issue persists...any idea why this would be working fine in Safari and not in Chrome?

Comment: That's a good question and I don't know the answer. Other than there could be a styling that you applied to an element that is rendering differently in Chrome. I don't have Safari so I can't take a look to see. I was able to make it look better by removing the push and pull column classes and applying a right float on the about_bg ID. But I'm sure that is not what you are wanting. Sorry I am not much more help! I think the push pull might be the issue, but that is just a guess since I don't have Safafi to test on.